# Is it possible to read all tweets by a certain user even if there are more than 5000?

Tags: twitter

I want to read someone's tweets from the past, but Twitter doesn't allow me to see more than 5000. How can I see them?

Answer (score 1):

[Twitter recently announced that they've made the search index of all public tweets available](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/building-a-complete-tweet-index).

[Re/code says](http://recode.net/2014/11/18/twitter-update-makes-all-public-tweets-searchable/):

> Previously, when you ran a search on Twitter.com or within the app, the search results prioritized tweets with high engagement (favorites and retweets), but didn’t include all tweets that might fit that search query. Now, every tweet relevant to each query will show up in results — you may just have to scroll for hours (days?) to get to it. In other words, the search functionality remains the same, the results are just more comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Twitter Search: Topsy](http://www.topsy.com) to search for public tweets of a user.

`from:username`

Select
"Sort by oldest"
"All Time" or "Specific Range" from the left sidebar.

Note: Oldest tweet in their archives seems date back to 2009 only.

Comment: Blame Apple. Topsy was shut down.

Answer (score -1):

There is an open source project I am affiliated with called bmtu https://github.com/insom/bmtu which can let you save tweets of any account. If you have trouble making it work, let me know and I will send you some modified version of the Python source code.

Answer (score -2):

snapbird.org is pretty great for that...all you have to do is sign in with your twitter account and then it'll let you pick who/what to backtrack on. -> http://snapbird.org/

you can access every tweet ever made via the library of congress, but you'll have to do more digging to find out how and where
here's info
http://www.loc.gov/today/pr/2013/files/twitter_report_2013jan.pdf

Comment: snapbird.org also let you retrieve the number of tweets as twitter does :(